# Replicate an SQL query in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSV file that I am reading and outputting to a JSON Object array, I'm trying to pull data out of the array to display. I'm trying to replicate the following SQL query.

```
SELECT requestor, SUM(change) as Total_Amount FROM `bankdump` WHERE `type`= 'purchase' group by requestor
```

This is the Array

```
[
{
    "transaction_id": "44b36e13-ba02-42a6-8b3a-82f6096ec3ba",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 18:28:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Winston Bolt",
    "account_id": "61408386"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "6482c419-ff8c-4121-98ae-6f2437646ba8",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 17:46:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Winston Bolt",
    "account_id": "61453979"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "0ab6c0cd-4389-4848-92f2-60b54982d5c7",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 17:42:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Winston Bolt",
    "account_id": "61428024"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "11580df3-6403-4cf9-a8b0-38b8b1b1b25f",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 17:28:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Erin Cox",
    "account_id": "61342083"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "3c6f93e5-ce24-405b-9558-44b2bf3f3653",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 17:26:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Ai Musori",
    "account_id": "61712295"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "a14712a0-8808-4686-99b2-ed9639d61fbc",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 15:15:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Ai Musori",
    "account_id": "61977423"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "def6ac07-6a7a-48c4-8534-0c68e8ddc46b",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 09:06:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Sean Tinker",
    "account_id": "61747726"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "f57432d0-b744-41ef-b6b8-af77b81b17ec",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 08:59:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: renewal",
    "requestor": "Sarah Ableton",
    "account_id": "61171658"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "ddcd5fd0-78c2-4e80-a603-09acb589122d",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 07:22:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Sean Tinker",
    "account_id": "61111782"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "7e359364-666d-41b3-a2cd-86ffac82e0a1",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 03:53:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership Renewal",
    "requestor": "Donovan King",
    "account_id": "61252737"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "448fefc0-4c35-48e4-b9ee-e2ab4e31b8aa",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 02:30:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership Fee",
    "requestor": "Donovan King",
    "account_id": "61994863"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "a4417a9c-fbd6-4b2d-8294-244e35dd7774",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 02:27:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Renewal",
    "requestor": "Donovan King",
    "account_id": "61773626"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "77c6cb44-9234-47b2-bc6a-6c71770e5621",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 00:58:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Barry Benson - Membership",
    "requestor": "Aleksander Sazkaljovich",
    "account_id": "61645306"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "d2dda96e-e5fa-485e-a866-3691e8f98f47",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 23:38:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Marlo Stanfield",
    "account_id": "61645416"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "fc6440d0-c5e7-435e-96f6-4ebec660397a",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 19:56:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Sarah Ableton",
    "account_id": "61937982"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "7b9e9c3a-a470-435d-907f-e23bd2d264e6",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 19:43:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "1000",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Gomer Colton",
    "account_id": "61364056"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "99a6c30a-d655-4e2f-9854-608521926afa",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 08:11:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Cassie Cupcake",
    "account_id": "61702462"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "ca9c56aa-aecb-4709-bcad-c4549e6d6929",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 08:09:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Cassie Cupcake",
    "account_id": "61410116"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "351deafc-ee03-4ca5-ab7e-facb31527034",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 07:33:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Cassie Cupcake",
    "account_id": "61116177"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "2f990c57-a1e2-4e0f-a5e1-bba5728945dc",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 07:32:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Cassie Cupcake",
    "account_id": "61674804"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "750ffbbe-851a-4601-b20e-f5e1d92fff5a",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-01 23:44:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership Fee",
    "requestor": "Claire  Seducer",
    "account_id": "61578674"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "7d8bf70e-f99a-4326-99f0-0f25e37bb651",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-01 17:01:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "500",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Erin Cox",
    "account_id": "61901342"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "96f100ea-c3e1-4d6e-9b2e-5a14abf6e4c9",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-01 16:07:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "withdraw",
    "change": "5000",
    "comment": "Expenses",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "64397152"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "ac38020e-bedc-485d-a64a-a56698b80fb6",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-01 15:45:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "500",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: PAYNE MEMBERSHIP RENEWAL",
    "requestor": "Erin Cox",
    "account_id": "61284625"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "2cd781db-af2f-4205-9b1b-2d3e5cf21767",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-01 15:40:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "500",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: MEMBERSHIP RENEWAL",
    "requestor": "Erin Cox",
    "account_id": "61496578"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "ae1311df-2b94-44f5-a77f-af080344b487",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 09:01:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Sean Tinker",
    "account_id": "61167813"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "7a95a07d-7851-4818-bb65-dd2fbcf8e216",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 08:37:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Cassie Cupcake",
    "account_id": "61838391"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "5cd49da0-8099-450c-9aa3-216c8ea7992d",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 08:33:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Cassie Cupcake",
    "account_id": "61718997"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "3eadcc1a-58a3-43bf-8d04-23fab3e461a0",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 03:20:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Riley Carter",
    "account_id": "61538217"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "5c72dee8-1176-40c5-8a2b-2a4fcddb81a1",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 03:19:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Violet Van Housen",
    "account_id": "61282400"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "fa231345-cb1a-4e54-82df-f4c7ae3b2c8d",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 03:18:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Riley Carter",
    "account_id": "61128317"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "3ac2b6ff-aa17-437b-bdf7-f72d53045888",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 03:17:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Violet Van Housen",
    "account_id": "61724462"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "fe14857d-1eea-4340-8c5d-7b5a5f8129e1",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 03:16:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Riley Carter",
    "account_id": "61453100"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "780132a8-b9ee-4302-be70-8fc70e7d7296",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 03:11:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Violet Van Housen",
    "account_id": "61848251"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "c895ce22-79e0-4821-9fdc-491045b7f9ec",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-00 01:32:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "10000",
    "comment": "Employee Payment: Salary (advance)",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61857315"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "28a034f4-1229-43a8-bd0d-2c0d26429353",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 20:23:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "10000",
    "comment": "Shaq / Abe Vaughn - Advertising @ No3",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61201843"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "e78a2121-3295-4634-a28d-d427ea7b7900",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 19:58:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "30000",
    "comment": "Employee Payment: Salary",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61143341"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "545d4003-8f16-468e-afc3-efa00ae95ae6",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 19:57:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "20000",
    "comment": "Car down payment",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61143341"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "283c6664-687c-48e4-bb78-09051c0c37b9",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 18:59:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Ai Musori",
    "account_id": "61824658"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "d53edd06-2858-4f30-9609-acb599e51abe",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 18:11:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Ai Musori",
    "account_id": "61437362"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "9994db52-22e3-4c4b-b56b-ceab12ecb0d6",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 15:04:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Ai Musori",
    "account_id": "61656896"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "b1ff9085-0799-4b89-a822-cffcd8f761b0",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 15:02:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Sean Tinker",
    "account_id": "61682962"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "81d9c5fd-36ed-4594-901b-a8039f535eeb",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 15:00:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "1000",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Gomer Colton",
    "account_id": "61901644"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "6ad3a76b-b2ab-44a5-9233-f337c474b75e",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 12:27:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Gomer Colton",
    "account_id": "61420031"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "4b294212-9451-4bc8-8950-3810c7e59765",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-06 12:24:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Gomer Colton",
    "account_id": "61267568"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "e827c214-cab2-48e7-8367-8061ed633988",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-04 01:41:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "20000",
    "comment": "Cassie car down payment",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61209808"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "47c64f4b-3196-477d-a336-be4fca4903b1",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-04 01:41:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "20",
    "comment": "Cassie car down payment",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61209808"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "b8833152-c541-40f9-b7cc-cfb6dc51cd02",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 15:24:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "transfer",
    "change": "100",
    "comment": "Employee Payment: Expemses",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61762557"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "3bf5298b-7411-4180-adeb-72abfa2bb903",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-03 00:30:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "withdraw",
    "change": "10000",
    "comment": "",
    "requestor": "Otto Delmar",
    "account_id": "64397152"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "cd394900-23c5-4130-86ca-a55671b3963c",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 20:26:00",
    "direction": "incoming",
    "type": "purchase",
    "change": "999",
    "comment": "Business Services Payment: Membership",
    "requestor": "Marlo Stanfield",
    "account_id": "61752944"
},
{
    "transaction_id": "d99042fa-ca26-4326-aa5d-5a8aafa1fce0",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02 20:21:00",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "type": "deposit",
    "change": "20000",
    "comment": "Business Payment: Bullshit fine coverage",
    "requestor": "Dean Watson",
    "account_id": "61762557"
}
]
```

I'm trying to end up with a list of requestors and their totals like so

[image: example output]

I want to keep it javascript or jquery strictly without using heavy libraries like node.js and others. I'm using jquery-csv to parse the CSV file on upload via jquery

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manvaril/yzLk2hed/)

Comment: what have you tried, please show your attempt. That is important

Comment: I have grouped by type as seen here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Manvaril/yzLk2hed/1)

Comment: I dont see any code, show us the code.

Comment: it's in the JSFiddle link right here [JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Manvaril/yzLk2hed/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this you can do with native array functions. But note that if you have big portion of data all will be cached..

Let's consider `json` to be the given array of json you provided:

1. best we start by filtering the stuff we want:

```js
const filtered = json.filter(o => o['type'] === 'purchase')
```

In the second step, simply pick the fields from the select clause via `Array.map()`

```js
const picked = filtered .map(o => {
  return { 
    requestor: o['requestor'],
    change: o['change'] 
 }
}
```

3. Now we have to apply the sum argument and also to group stuff togehter. This goes all under the name `Array.reduce()`.  We start merging the data into one big object (make it grouped! , we **reduce** it!, ') , holding the sum of changes per entry:

```js
const grouped_table = data.reduce((grouped, current_object) => {

    // get the requestor
    const requestor = current_object['requestor']

    // first we make sure to store the requestor atleasst once.
    // So if it DOES NOT exist, simply add it with number 0!, in case no
    // changes were found at all for this reqeustor.
    if(typeof grouped[requestor] !== 'number') {
        grouped[requestor] = 0
    }

    // Now that we are sure, the field is set, We add the 
    // change if there is one!

    // get the change value:
    const change = parseInt(current_object['change'])

    // If the change is not a valid number, resp. null or similar, we do not want
    // to add it. We return the state as we already havethe requestor group created.
    if(change === NaN) {
        return grouped
    }

    // change is number, and group is created. Sum it up!
    grouped[requestor] += change

    // make sure to return the grouped ofc!!
    return grouped

// note that the "{}" in the next line, is actually the start value for the "grouped" variable! 
}, {})
```

The data looks now like that:

[image]

4. Now you have an object, Holding all requestor names as entries and all changes as it's values. You can now iterate over it with `Object.keys()`

```js
const requestors = Object.keys(grouped_table).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`Requestor "${key}" has a change of ${grouped_table[key]} !`)
}

// Output:
// Requestor "Winston Bolt" has a change of  => 9990
// Requestor "Erin Cox" has a change of  => 10491
// etc.
```

#### Resume

That should give you an idea how you can adapt `sql` queries to javascript without big dependencies. You should focus on learning the native `Array` Methods. !

### Full Code:

```js
const filtered = json.filter(o => o['type'] === 'purchase')

const picked = filtered .map(o => {
  return { 
    requestor: o['requestor'],
    change: o['change'] 
 }
}

const grouped_table = data.reduce((grouped, current_object) => {

    // get the requestor
    const requestor = current_object['requestor']

    // first we make sure to store the requestor atleasst once.
    // So if it DOES NOT exist, simply add it with number 0!, in case no
    // changes were found at all for this reqeustor.
    if(typeof grouped[requestor] !== 'number') {
        grouped[requestor] = 0
    }

    // Now that we are sure, the field is set, We add the 
    // change if there is one!

    // get the change value:
    const change = parseInt(current_object['change'])

    // If the change is not a valid number, resp. null or similar, we do not want
    // to add it. We return the state as we already havethe requestor group created.
    if(change === NaN) {
        return grouped
    }

    // change is number, and group is created. Sum it up!
    grouped[requestor] += change

    // make sure to return the grouped ofc!!
    return grouped
// note that the "{}" in the next line, is actually the start value for the "grouped" variable! 
}, {})



// you can access final summed up data here and put names on it as you want.
const requestors = Object.keys(grouped_table).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`Requestor "${key}" has a change of ${grouped_table[key]} !`)
}

// Output:
// Requestor "Winston Bolt" has a change of  => 9990
// Requestor "Erin Cox" has a change of  => 10491
// etc.
```

Comment: I had to figure out how to manipulate the data to get it into a table but I figured it out, this is a perfect answer, I will also look into Arrays more

Comment: Great! , If you also want a native csv parsing method have a look at this post => 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Works like a harm!

Comment: Ask a new question, someone will answer it